# customizable interval timer with batch

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering, with batch, if there was a way to make a counter with a programmable interval. For example if i wanted to go into the actual code for the file and set the interval to 4 seconds, then once i run the batch file, every four seconds, it will add one to the counter. Then, If i were to want to change it i just go into the text file and change it to, say 10 seconds, and run the program again and have it add one every ten seconds? I hope i explained this well enough. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: add some code you have tried for that purpose, rather than simply stating your question in english.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't ask for code but rather help/pointers on your pre-existing code. However, there is a very simple way to do this. Since the post is a little unclear on your request, it sounds like your asking to read a text file for a number (x), then have the batch file count +1 for every x seconds.

To do this, we can grab the number from the text file and create a string from it. From there we can make a count down loop to count down from x number. Afterwards, we can add +1 from and string and send it back to the countdown. To break this whole loop (If you wish to), you can use a `if ""=="" ()` statement to look for . I have left this at the bottom. You can use this as needed.

If this code helps and solved your issue, please check it as solved, if not, please comment how I can improve my response.

**filename.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
SET count=-1
GOTO DONE

:CONTINUE

:: This module will count down from the number in the text file
set /a sec-=1
if "%sec%"=="-1" goto DONE
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL
goto CONTINUE

:DONE
cls

:: Get NUMBER From a text file
for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%~dp0number.txt") do set "sec=%%I"

:: Add one to %count% and display it
set /a count+=1
echo Current count: %count%

:: Return to loop or exit if exceeded limit.
if not "%count%"=="5" GOTO CONTINUE
```

**number.txt**

```
4
```